# Excel 2010 32-bit mscomctl.ocx reference missing

Tags: excel-2010

I have a book with macro and forms in it. 
when i open the book a run time error appears and when i look in vba
tools-> reference

Microsoft Windows Common Tools is not referenced and
the reference file path is C:\Windows\SysWow64\MSCOMCTL.OCX

OS: Windows 7 SP 1 32-bit

Microsoft Excel 2010 32-bit

Other info:

The book/file is something I didn't create in my unit, its something i received

Some file work properly but some wont (those file have the same codes inside)

Does anyone knows how to fix this problem? and possible reasons why this occur?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what solves your problem:
http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/5b241f09-6c76-4320-b302-4cb8224eab7f/controls-from-mscomctlocx-can-no-longer-be-used-in-excel-2010-32bit:

> 1. Run CMD under administrator mode
> 2. run "REGSVR32 MSCOMCTL.OCX" without the quote

Comment: I had already done that but unfortunately, it didn't fix the problem. Thanks anyway